# Not reading value

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 rows of numbers in a source workbook. I would like to copy the first row into another workbook, then make the row below it the sum of the source's first & second rows. My code runs but I can't seem to get excel to read the values of the second row. (aa is the source workbook's sheet)

```
With aa
    For i = 1 To Range(Range("U2").Offset(1, 0), Range("U2").Offset(1, 0).End(xlToRight)).Cells.Count
        Set NewValue = Range("U2").Offset(1, i - 1)
        TargetWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Offset(1, i - 1).Value = Range("D2").Offset(0, i - 1) + NewValue.Value
    Next
End With
```

Comment: You're not linking your `Range()` calls to the `With` block.  `For i = 1 To .Range(.Range("U2").Offset(1, 0),....`  etc

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tim! I think i get it now.